# Wrong size in dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, malloc, sizeof

I am puzzled by the output of this code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define TIMING_OUTPUT_FILENAME_MAX_LENGTH 40

    int main (int argc, char **argv)
    {
        char *timing_output_filename = malloc(TIMING_OUTPUT_FILENAME_MAX_LENGTH);
        printf("requested buffer size is %ld bytes and pointer size is %ld bytes\n", 
        sizeof(timing_output_filename),
        sizeof(*timing_output_filename));

        return 0;
    }
```

and here is the output:

```
requested buffer size is 8 bytes and pointer size is 1 bytes
```

It's supposed to return me 40 bytes? Am I missing something?

Comment: Pointers are not arrays.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> *It's supposed to return me 40 bytes?*

No, it's not.

In your code, `timing_output_filename` is a pointer and using `sizeof` operator on a pointer yields the size of the pointer itself, not the size of the allocated memory (to the pointer).

In your code, `sizeof(timing_output_filename)` is the same as `sizeof(char *)`, so it produces the size of a pointer to `char` as in your platform.

Note: `sizeof` produces a result of type `size_t`, so you should use `%zu` format specifier to print the result.

Comment: agreed. But how do I know it has **really** allocated 40 bytes for me?

Comment: @Black_Zero What do you mean **really**? Check for the return value, check against NULL.

Comment: @Black_Zero It will either return a pointer to the memory with requested size, or return NULL. there's nothin in between. :)